# TeXMaker - automatically show structure fully opened in PDF

Tags: texmaker, options

When i use the "PDFLaTeX"-tool and click "show PDF", TeXMaker always shows me the structure where i only see the chapters. Is there a way of setting a preference to open all chapters, sections and subsections in the structure automatically?
EDIT: Maybe i should've mentioned, that i am using MacTex and TeXMaker on Mac OSX

Comment: Do you use an external PDF viewer?

Comment: no, i don't use one yet, should i?